# Transforming temp table that uses counts into query

Tags: sql-server, count, subquery, temp-tables

Today I came by one query that I deem to be 'suboptimal'

it looks following:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( 
                    Sessionid    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
                    PolicyNumber VARCHAR(30), 
                    StartDate    DATETIME, 
                    RequestUrl   VARCHAR(255), 
                    ClientSource VARCHAR(50),
                    Comment VARCHAR(250),
                    ExceptionCount INT 
                ) 

                INSERT INTO #temp 
                    SELECT sessionid, policynumber, startdate  "Timestamp", requesturl "Instance", clientsource , '' Comment 
                    , (SELECT COUNT(*) from Logging.Exceptions where [Key] = sessionId) as exceptioncount 
                    FROM   [Transaction].[sessions] tr WITH  (nolock)
                     WHERE sessionId = '7B851237-3790-4A6D-9688-2E77843E0BB1' 

                SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE exceptioncount > -1) as TotalRecords,
                       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE exceptioncount > -1) as TotalDisplayRecords,* from
                    (SELECT * FROM
                        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate  desc) AS rownumber,
                            sessionid, policynumber, startdate  "Timestamp", requesturl "Instance", 
                            clientsource, exceptioncount,Comment            
                         FROM #temp
                         WHERE exceptioncount > -1) as cte
                     WHERE cte.rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10) as "Results"


                drop table #temp
```

which I have now rewritten in a following form

```
SELECT   
--count(*) TotalRecords,
 --   count(*) TotalDisplayRecords,
                       * from (

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Timestamp"  desc) AS rownumber, * from (
                        SELECT sessionid, policynumber, startdate  "Timestamp", requesturl "Instance", clientsource , '' Comment 
                    , (SELECT COUNT(1) from Logging.Exceptions where [Key] = sessionId) as exceptioncount
                    FROM   [Transaction].[sessions] tr WITH  (nolock)
                     WHERE sessionId = '7B851237-3790-4A6D-9688-2E77843E0BB1' ) withrownumber 
                     WHERE exceptioncount > -1 ) as cte
```

the only thing that is missing is adding counts, **Is there a way to do this without having to repeat bulk of main select?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

Here I have replaced Co-related Sub query with `Outer Apply`. Up to my knowledge Corelated Sub query will compare every record of Outer Set with every record of Inner set. Where as Outer Apply will execute per row once.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS rownumber
    , sessionid
    , policynumber
    , startdate  AS [Timestamp]
    , requesturl AS [Instance]
    , clientsource
    , '' Comment
    , EXC.exceptioncount 
    FROM [Transaction].[sessions] tr WITH (NOLOCK)
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS exceptioncount 
            FROM Logging.Exceptions
            WHERE [Key] = tr.sessionId
    )AS EXC
    WHERE sessionId = '7B851237-3790-4A6D-9688-2E77843E0BB1'
)

SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CTE WHERE exceptioncount > - 1 ) AS TotalRecords
,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CTE WHERE exceptioncount > - 1 ) AS TotalDisplayRecords
, sessionid
, policynumber
, [Timestamp]
, [Instance]
, clientsource
, Comment
, exceptioncount 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, I don't like it very much and would appreciate if someone would come up with more elegant solution

```
    select * from 
            (SELECT   
                count(1) TotalRecords,
                count(1) TotalDisplayRecords,
                * from (
                    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Timestamp"  desc) AS rownumber, * from (
                        SELECT sessionid, policynumber, startdate  "Timestamp", requesturl "Instance", clientsource, 
                            (SELECT COUNT(1) from Logging.Exceptions  WITH  (nolock) where [Key] = sessionId) as exceptioncount,
                        '' Comment 
                        FROM [Transaction].[sessions] tr WITH (nolock)
                        WHERE sessionId = '7B851237-3790-4A6D-9688-2E77843E0BB1') withrownumber 
                WHERE exceptioncount > -1 ) as cte
                group by rownumber, sessionid, policynumber,  "Timestamp",  "Instance", clientsource ,  Comment, exceptioncount) as r
        WHERE r.rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```